# Ansible send consolidated mail for inventory hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

i was trying to perform blkid check on multiple hosts and if there is any failure on any node , ansible should send email for those particular hosts. but i am getting mails for each host individually rather than i want all the failed hosts in a single mail

any help?

main.yml

```
- name: check blkid
  block:

    - name: checking blkid on multiple hosts
      shell: /sbin/blkid
      failed_when: cmd.rc != 0
      register: cmd
    tags:
      - checkblkid
  rescue:
    - name: send email for command execution failed hosts
      mail:
        host: localhost
        to: xxxx@gmail.com
        subject: list of hosts blkid not found
        subtype: html
        body: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      tags:
        - checkblkid
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.. get all failed hosts into a common variable/fact and the send mail using `run_once: true`

```
- name: set failed_hosts
  set_fact:
    failed_hosts: ""
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: check blkid
  block:

    - name: checking blkid on multiple hosts
      shell: /sbin/blkid
      failed_when: cmd.rc != 0
      register: cmd
    tags:
      - checkblkid
  rescue:
    - name: add host to failed_hosts
      set_fact:
        failed_hosts: "{{ failed_hosts }}, {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      tags:
        - checkblkid

- name: send email for command execution failed hosts
  mail:
    host: localhost
    to: xxxx@gmail.com
    subject: list of hosts blkid not found
    subtype: html
    body: "{{ failed_hosts }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
  tags:
    - checkblkid
```